# Get Firebase Web Notification Even Close Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firebase, web, google-chrome-extension, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently working on a video web application. We rely on notification to notify provider there is call in.

Firebase works well even when I close the tab. I found that if there is any chrome's thread running in background, I will get notification.

Is there any way that I can make a background thread active even the user click close button on chrome? how about chrome extension? does it approach the goal?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions#background or chrome://flags/#enable-push-api-background-mode

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging for web relies on a service worker to receive messages when the web app is not active/visible. This requires that Chrome is active.

If the user completely quits Chrome, all tabs, service workers and extensions are stopped. There is no way to still receive web push notifications in that case.

Comment: I really appreciate that your answers. I completely understand your description. Any idea that I can ask chrome to launch  a background thread to run some code? I notice that when I open a chrome extension , like the postman, there is chrome thread always alive even I close all the tab. So I am thinking if I mv my web app to chrome extension app, there will be some  api or function that I can ask chrome to open a background thread for me. In javascript it is not way that I can ask chrome to to that, right? Do you think this way is doable？

Comment: The only Chrome extension I regularly use (Hangouts) closes (after a short prompt) when I close Chrome. I've never tried myself to keep a Chrome process alive after killing the browser window. As a user I'd probably be pretty upset if that would be common, since I'd have to revert to restarting my OS to restart such processes.